# Alert is getting triggered automatically in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am  new to reactjs, I have been trying to design a UI such that o every click it displays alert telling this li element is clicked but when the page is rendered I see lot of alerts getting popped out. Can someone point out mistake in my code and how to avoid it!

Here is the code snippet

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!-- <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" /> -->
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <title>Grade Score</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';

function clickhandle (props) {
  alert("you clicked on" + props.name)
}

function Stud(props) {
  return <li onClick={clickhandle(props)}> { props.name }</li>;
  
}

function App() {
  const students = ['Anil', 'Bob' , 'Clara', 'Dew', 'John', 'Ravi', 'Ram'];
  return (
    <>
     <ul>
        {students.map((student) => <Stud name={student} />)}
      </ul>
    </>
  );
}
```

I want the alerts to be displayed only if I click on the li element but in my my code it continuously pops up alert as soon as page loads!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are calling the function when the page loads. You have to pass a function to `onClick`, not call the function directly:

```
onClick={() => clickhandle(props)}
```